# Trouble with Non-Native Menu in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a `select` that I'd like to use the custom menu display (rather than native) in jQuery Mobile.  However, I'm just getting [strange behavior out of the non-native menu (jsfiddle link)](http://jsfiddle.net/kyrVY/7/).  In this case, the non-native menu is only showing one of my three options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue right after I posted it.  Every `option` needs a `value` attribute set ([corrected jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kyrVY/8/)).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many options you have, radio buttons groups might be a better option.  The problem with any select is that it requires the user to act before ever seeing what their options are.  From a user experience perspective, if you don't have a vast amount of options,  use radio buttons.  [This section of a blog post](http://roughlybrilliant.com/jquery_mobile_best_practices#6) I wrote might help.

Comment: Thanks, but on a space-constrained device, progressive disclosure often wins even though it requires one more touch/click.

Comment: Not necessarily unless you believe in "the fold."  But ultimately, this is one of those "it depends" answers that will differ from form to form.